# Unable to update database using SaveChanges()

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

Context.SaveChanges() is not updating database. I understand there might be some issue about attached or detached object but I could not figure it out. What could have gone wrong here?

```
        public ActionResult DeleteSupplier(int supplierId)
        {
            using (var db = new InventoryDbContext())
            {
                Suppliers ss = (from s in db.supplier
                                             where s.supplierId == supplierId
                                             select s).FirstOrDefault();
                db.supplier.Remove(ss);
                db.Entry(ss).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

Jquery/ajax codes:

```
//Delete event handler.
            $("body").on("click", "#tblss .Delete", function () {
                if (confirm("Do you want to delete this row?")) {
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                    var supplierId = row.find("span").html();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/Master/DeleteSupplier",
                        data: '{supplierId: ' + supplierId + '}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            if ($("#tblss tr").length > 2) {
                                row.remove();
                            } else {
                                row.find(".Edit").hide();
                                row.find(".Delete").hide();
                                row.find("span").html('&nbsp;');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `db.Entry(ss).State = EntityState.Deleted;
`?

Comment: so just to make sure, how do i double check there is no 'other db instance'?

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to figure out. It has to do with the View page whereby the javascript was reading the Ids from span but the syntax was omitted from the html page.